# Create SQLite DB from entity model programmatically C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, sqlite

I am writing **WinForms** application in Visual Studio 2017. I am using **SQLite** Database because my program should work without Internet connection and no option to install **SQL Server**. This program going to be used by common people and they will be given only .exe file to work with. So when my application opening I need to check if SQLite database exist if not it must be created. Problem is when I delete database and try following code:

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\USR-pc\Desktop\test.db"))
{
     SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"C:\Users\USR-pc\Desktop\test.db");
     mainEntities db = new mainEntities();
     db.Database.Create();
     db.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

And I get error No Entity Framework provider found for the **ADO.NET** provider with invariant name `Devart.Data.SQLite`. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mainEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=Devart.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\Users\USR-pc\Desktop\test.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

I downloaded dcsqlite.exe and Installed it. After using **NuGet** I installed SQLite to my project. After that I built Ado.net entity model using entity framework. From this model I want to create new database if it does not exist.